# problem facing with android application on two different android platform O.S. device

Tags: android

I have build one android application in androids version(2.2) and i have specified minimum sdk version in android manifest file as 3 i.e (version-1.5) .so i have to make sure that this application should run successfully on api leval of device having from 3 i.e Version(1.5) to 8 Version(2.2but since contact content provider for android Api platform "leval(4)" and "leval(8)" are different,and in my application i am using contact content provider,i am facing exceptions as "illegal argument","null pointer","uncought exception" at runtime.

On the other side if i build the application with version(1.6),It not gives runtime exception but when i tried to get contact details from device e.g(phone number,email),it gives null value as "null pointer" exception.

do you have any proper solution for this.please replay..

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to ship one version of your app, you should use [android.os.Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) to determine the API level, and thus the right API to use.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Answer (score 0):

The attribute android:minSdk does not guarantee that your application will run on these devices (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#min)).